# Putting employer or client company as experience

Tags: work-experience, linkedin

I was hired by company X months ago as a full time developer but have been working onsite as a contractor at one of company X's clients, company Y.  I might be somewhat bias but since company Y is more renowned and respectable in the industry, I am wondering if I should leave company X in the dark?

Although I am working as a contractor at Y, I have never visited X (company is out of country) and it was one of Y's managers who did the initial interview with me.  I checked other developers who are also from X and some of them put X on their profile, some of which put Y, some even put both.  Which makes me wonder if its okay to not bring up X and only mention company Y in my resume / linkedin / interviews unless they ask?

Comment: Unless there is some sort of confidentiality agreement, I'd put the better known one or both. **January 2013-Present: Company X** Supported Company Y on-site, doing A, B, and C.

Comment: I am currently in the same dilemma but would be adding the info as a `Project` on `LinkedIn` would help?

Comment: Not quite sure why my question is marked as duplicate when my question was clearly asked prior to the one linked....

Answer (score 8):

I actually err on the side of listing whomever I'm legally an employee of and "working at". So it could be...

Software Development Engineer - Company X at Company Y

Maybe I'm a minority but I might find it dishonest to list "Company Y" as your employer if you are legally employed by someone else and working there on site.

Comment: Not to mention that it's incredibly easy to check. I wouldn't want to have to explain to my employer why I said I was employed by Company Y when Company Y says I wasn't an employee and they have no record of me working for them.