# Which company to mention in Job Title for a Consultant

Tags: resume, linkedin, consultants

I am currently working as a consultant from one company (my Parent company on whose payroll I am) to another company (where I actually work, my parent company's client). What I actually work on, therefore, has nothing to do with my parent company.

Which company is more appropriate for listing on my job title in my resume and on LinkedIn. Should I say I am at position XYZ at the Parent company or I am a Consultant at the Client company. I mean only the job title, I know I can clarify everything in the description but title alone is also important.

---

<sub>PS: I just found that this already has an answer at [Putting employer or client company as experience](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/10597/putting-employer-or-client-company-as-experience?rq=1). Unless there is anything to add, this question should probably be marked as duplicate.</sub>

Comment: Actually, the only answer there suggests using something like `Software Development Engineer - Company X at Company Y`. Can I do that on LinkedIn.

Comment: Sure.  You can do that on LinkedIn.

Comment: @JustinCave How? In the `Title` I can put `Software Development Engineer`. In the `Company name` I can put `Company X`. Where do I put Company Y.